# best database table structure for calendar meeting app for PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, database-design

Here is info on the application -

There are multiple staff who can log from what time to what time they are available and the users can select a time slot for meeting with 30 mins duration.

So, what would be the efficient way to go about doing in terms of `table schema`

Currently, I've one table called `staff_availability` which looks like this

```
| id | staff_id   | day_of_week | from_time | to_time |
|----|------------|-------------|-----------|---------|
| 1  | staff_id_1 | 1           | 10:00     | 14:00   |
| 2  | staff_id_1 | 1           | 15:00     | 17:00   |
| 3  | staff_id_2 | 1           | 10:00     | 12:00   |
```

`day_of_week` is the day with 0 based index where `0 is Sunday` and `6 is Saturday`.

There will also be another `meetings` table

```
| id | staff_id   | from_timestamp      | to_timestamp        | status                     | rescheduled_meeting_id                           |
|----|------------|---------------------|---------------------|----------------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | staff_id_1 | 2022-07-10 10:30:00 | 2022-07-10 11:30:00 | cancelled/done/rescheduled | id of rescheduled_meeting_id_in_case_rescheduled |
| 2  | staff_id_1 | 2022-7-10 13:00:00  | 2022-07-10 13:30:00 |                            |                                                  |
```

Is it a good schema?

The problem that I've is:
when the user selects a date, I need to show which time slots are available by 30 mins span. So, if a user selects `2022-07-10`, no staff is available from 10:00 - 10:30 it should not show that. It would show something like
available time slots
10:30-11:00, 11:00-11:30,... by taking both `staff_availability`, `meetings` tables into consideration.
So, how do I go about solving it?

I'm open to any suggestions. If you think, there is a better schema to go about solving this problem, I'm open to it as well.

Comment: For a calendar I would use at least a range-datatype, to support constraints on overlapping schedules. Datatype tstzrange that is: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN

Comment: Hey @FrankHeikens thank you. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Storing the day_of_week is a poor plan. What happens when a staff member is NOT available at the same time of a day every week. Also as the interval suggestion from   @FrankHeiken  what other would you like; it is the proper approach.

Comment: @Belayer That's a good point. Availablity by individual date is preferred and in this case, it makes my case easier now. I will post how I solved it once I'm done with this.

Comment: If anyone has any more suggestions, feel free to suggest. I'm looking forward to more suggestions.